# html file hosting using OWIN

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a console application as a host for webapi. It works fine and serves the API controller. I also want to add an HTML file to the same console application and get it hosted using the Microsoft.OWIN.StaticFiles middleware and using the following code in StartUp.cs.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

        string exeFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string webFolder = Path.Combine(exeFolder,"/TestFolder");
        appBuilder.UseStaticFiles(webFolder);
    }
```

But when i try to browse the page using the Url, i get error

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9999/testfolder/samplehtml.html'.No type was found that matches the controller named 'testfolder'.

It seems like the Folder named "TestFolder" is being treated like a API controller. Is it possible to achieve something like this or what could be the point I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. I had to change the Routing template to add a constant prefix 'api'. So the new routing template became:

```
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Note the use of 'api' keyword. This differentiates my two requests as the system now knows that it needs to look for an API controller only when the url contains the keyword. So when I need to send the api request, use

http://localhost:8888/api/sample/getdate

and for html page, use

http://localhost:8888/testfolder/sample.html